# Shell Script for file monitoring

Tags: shell

I have 2 AWS EC2 LAMP servers and i want to replicate the data on  one of the folders to others. I know I can try with EFS, but for some reason it is not a viable option at this moment. So, here is what I want to request for help:

Our Server A and Server B has same file structure but the files inside are mismatch. So, I want a script in Server A to look in, example, /var/www/html/../file/ folder and compare with /var/www/html/../file/ in Server B, and dump all new files from Server A to B.

Any help on how to write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I used S3FS which is lot easier than breaking head over the script. It readily copies the files from one server to another.